# Join two table and sum count record

Tags: mysql, join, record, min

I need to join two tables, my tables:

table 1

```
user           ip                  amount          time    
user1       10.12.130.14            5000         1409007653
user2       10.12.130.13            2000         1309007653
user3       10.12.130.12            4000         1209007653
user4       10.12.130.11            6000         1109007653
...
```

table 2

```
ref             ip                      time    
ref1         10.12.130.14             1209007653
ref1         10.12.130.13             1109007653
ref1         10.12.130.12             1309007653
ref2         10.12.130.11             1409007653
...
```

I need the result: ( foreach  all ref )

```
ref              allcount          todaycont           allsum          todaysum     
ref1                 3                 1                11000             5000 
ref2                 1                 0                6000                0 
...
```

The code that I wrote but it's not complete:

```
$query  =   mysql_query("SELECT table2.ref, table1.user 
FROM 
table2 INNER JOIN table1 
ON 
table2.ip = table1.ip 
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What are your attempts so far? What is your definition of the columns in the joined result set?

Comment: what have tried so far...??

Comment: i need join table 1 and table 2 , table1 join table2 = result table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but by my interpretation of your question, this should work:

```
SELECT
    A.ref,
    COUNT(*) allcount,
    CASE
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(A.time,'%m-%y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%y')
            THEN COUNT(*)
    END todaycount,
    SUM(A.amount),
    CASE
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(A.time,'%m-%y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%y')
            THEN SUM(A.amount)
    END todaysum
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B
    ON A.ip = B.ip
GROUP BY
    B.ref
```

The biggest part I'm unsure of is the date/time segments in the case statements. That's mostly due to my unfamiliarity with the date/time format that you're using in your table, they should work if tweaked properly for your datatype.